# Is it possible to add headers to each UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'd like to add section header style headers, except for each individual cell. Each cell would have a date label floating above it, with a transparent background. These labels would be "attached" to each cell, but not actually be touching those cells. Is it possible to do this without turning each cell into its own section and just using header sections?

Example:
[image]

Comment: I think no good way to do it ,but turning cell into section, or just take the label as a part of cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't require header if you want design like your screenshot, You can directly design cell as you want.

Just put that label outside of view and give appropriate spacing.

All the best!!

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Turns out I can programmatically add elements that exist outside of the cell `contentView` bounds, so this worked.